# How do you programmatically set an attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, object

Suppose I have a python object `x` and a string `s`, how do I set the attribute `s` on `x`? So:

```
>>> x = SomeObject()
>>> attr = 'myAttr'
>>> # magic goes here
>>> x.myAttr
'magic'
```

What's the magic? The goal of this, incidentally, is to cache calls to `x.__getattr__()`.

Answer (score 378, accepted):

```
setattr(x, attr, 'magic')
```

For help on it:

```
>>> help(setattr)
Help on built-in function setattr in module __builtin__:

setattr(...)
    setattr(object, name, value)
    
    Set a named attribute on an object; setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to
    ``x.y = v''.
```

However, you should note that you can't do that to a "pure" instance of `object`. But it is likely you have a simple subclass of object where it will work fine. I would strongly urge the O.P. to never make instances of object like that.

Comment: Careful, however, this doesn't work in your scenario where you're creating an instance of object().

Comment: Absolutely right, it doesn't. I conveniently ignored that. I would strongly urge the O.P. to never make instances of object like that.

Comment: Damn shame it doesn't work in all cases, as that would be really useful, for example, for adding the `dirty` attribute to user input...

Comment: @Brice:  setattr works in almost all cases.  For efficiency and other reasons, 'object' is programmed so that you cannot add extra attributes to it.  You can do this with your own class with the `__slots__` attribute.

Comment: This does not work on `int` as well. Can you explain why? (is it on all `__builtin__`'s?

Comment: @JensTimmerman: Practically speaking, because integers are supposed to be immutable.  The implementation [interns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) small integers, strings, and some other builtin immutable types.  If you were allowed to set arbitrary attributes on those types, this interning would break in a variety of subtle and confusing ways.

Comment: One should be able to subclass `int` using the `type(cls, (int,), kwargs)` pattern? (I subclass `float` on a regular basis and override `__init__` in the custom float to add custom attributes)

Answer (score 66):

Usually, we define classes for this.

```
class XClass( object ):
   def __init__( self ):
       self.myAttr= None

x= XClass()
x.myAttr= 'magic'
x.myAttr
```

However, you can, to an extent, do this with the `setattr` and `getattr` built-in functions.  However, they don't work on instances of `object` directly.

```
>>> a= object()
>>> setattr( a, 'hi', 'mom' )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'hi'
```

They do, however, work on all kinds of simple classes.

```
class YClass( object ):
    pass

y= YClass()
setattr( y, 'myAttr', 'magic' )
y.myAttr
```

Comment: Any insight on why this does not work with instances of object()?

Comment: @meawoppl You should ask that as a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: can I do this with Modules, instead of Classes?

Comment: The link in @jalanb's comment is 404.

Answer (score 23):

let x be an object then you can do it two ways

```
x.attr_name = s 
setattr(x, 'attr_name', s)
```

Comment: This doesn't always work

Comment: @MarkRucker if x is user defined object, it should work. but with something which comes with python, it won't. What did not work for you ?

Comment: I was just leaving a note for people in the future that there are unaddressed limitations with this answer. For those who need to know, these limitations are addressed in the two answers above this.

Answer (score 2):

Also works fine within a class:

```
def update_property(self, property, value):
   setattr(self, property, value)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want a filename from an argument:

```py
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

file = open(filename, 'r')

contents = file.read()
```

If you want an argument to show on your terminal (using `print()`):

```py
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1]

arg1config = print(arg1config)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).