# Python + making a function more generic

Tags: python, django

I wanted some guidance if possible on how to make this more generic:

```
def get_industry_choices(self):
    industries = Industry.objects.all().order_by('name')
    ind_arr = [(ind.id, ind.name) for ind in industries]

    return ind_arr
```

Basically this function will return `choices` as expected for the `forms.ChoiceField`. I need to do this in a few places, and wanted to make the function above more generic. I know how to get the `industries = Industry.objects.all().order_by('name')` to be generic, but the 2nd part is what I'm not sure about. When creating the tuples, it has `(ind.id, ind.name)`. the `ind.name` can be any value depending on the model passed in (it may not always have `name` in the model).

I tried to read up on this in a few places including:

[Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python)

The above resource shows how to do it using a function passed in, but that seems a bit overkill? If I have to pass a function as an argument anyway, whats the point of making it more generic with one more function?

**[EDIT]**

Basically I want to produce something similar to this:

```
TITLE_CHOICES=(
    (1, 'Mr.'),
    (2, 'Ms.'),
    (3, 'Mrs.'),
    (4, 'Dr.'),
    (5, 'Prof.'),
    (6, 'Rev.'),
    (7, 'Other'),
)
```

So when doing `forms.ChoiceField` I can pass in `TITLE_CHOICES` for example as the possible choices. The first value is the value I get when the form is submitted, the second value is what the user sees on form. I want to be able to programmatically create this with any model, I pass in the model name and one field in the above example, `name`. I want to create the tuple such that it is `(id, name)`. But `name` could be replaced with anything in a different model...

Comment: +1 for searching for an answer first

Comment: Sorry if there was confusion...but was wondering if there was something I was missing, trying to make the above function as generic as possible.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to pass in any Model and create a tuple from the `id` and a particular field in it.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell from your question, but I think the bit you are missing is [getattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr). For example

```
ind = something()
for field in ['id', 'name']:
    print getattr(ind, field)
```

Comment: That worked! thanks. I never used the `getattr` method before.

Comment: Do not create new tag such as `gimme-codez`.  Just flag the question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Django already has a shortcut for this: `values_list`.

```
Industry.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
```

or

```
fields = ['id', 'name']
Industry.objects.all().values_list(*fields)
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, but only for this specific use case. So i'll keep the other as the answer since it'll work in most other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
from some_app.models import SomeModel


def generate_choices(model, order=None *args):
    choices = model.objects
    if order:
        choices = choices.order_by(order)
    return choices.values_list('pk', *args)


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choice_field = CharField(max_length=1,
                                choices=generate_choices(SomeModel, 'name'))
    other_choice_field = CharField(max_length=1,
                                   choices=generate_choices(SomeModel, 'city', 'state'))
```