# Create an attribute with a variable as name

Tags: python

Sometimes, I try to use a variable to name a function:

```
myVar = "something"

def myVar () :
    pass
```

The function thus created is not `something()` but `myVar()`.

Same problem with `global`:

```
myVar = "something"

global myVar
```

In this example, the variable isn't `something` but it's `myVar`.

Actually, my problem is similar; I want to create an attribute from a variable:

```
class myClass :

    def __init__ (self) :
        myVar = "something"
        self.myVar = 1
```

Without surprise the attribute create in this example is `self.myVar`, not `self.something`.

Generally I try to avoid these kinds of problems by rethinking my code. But I would like to know if there is a way to do it?

Comment: See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/285061/3001761

Comment: Thanks  jonrsharpe. I found the solution in stackoverflow.com/q/285061/3001761. Use setattr (self, myVar, 1) instead of self.myVar = 1 work perfectly.

Comment: @Morgan Be sure to read the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164, e.g. "It's more than a "bad" thing. It's perfectly horrifying.". Instead it's better to rethink your code and avoid it (as you already stated).

Comment: thanks syntonym, I saw this comment.