# Add values to a class in Python

Tags: python, class, variables

Let's say I have the following in Python:

```
class Test():
    self.value1 = 1
    self.value2 = 2

def setvalue1(self, value):
    self.value1 = value
```

So one can set up value1 by doing:

```
Test.setvalue1('Hola')
```

or

```
Test.Value1 = 'Hola'
```

So far so good. My problem is I would like to set the values by reading them somewhere else so for instance I could have the following:

```
A = [['Value1','Hola'],['Value2','Adios']]
```

I would like to be able to run something that will do (in pseudo code):

```
for each in A:
    Test.each[0] = A[1]
```

Is this possible? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the indention of your code as intended? Is `setvalue1` a member of `Test`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute-in-python

Comment: isn't `self` undefined at the point you've set `self.value1 = 1`?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like that:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val1 = 1



t = Test()
setattr(t, 'val2', 2)

print t.val2
```

Or like that:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val1 = 1

    def setself(self, name, val):
        self.__dict__[name] = val

t = Test()
t.setself('val3', 3)

print t.val3
```

Comment: Unless you know *very exactly* what you're doing,  the correct solution is `setattr()`, which will respect the descriptor protocol (computed attributes) while directly setting `self.__dict__` wont.

Comment: Hmm, good to know, I'll look this up

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your data structure and use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) on an instance of your class `Test`:

```
test = Test()

data = [('Value1', 'Hola'), ('Value2', 'Adios']
for k, v in data:
    setattr(test, k, v)
```

This kind of data structure btw is generally considered a "key/value" pair and you could use a Python dictionary (`dict`) here.

Example:

```
test = Test()

data = {"value1": "Hola", "Value2": "Adios"}
for k, v in data.items()
    setattr(test, k, v)
```

Now let's fix up your `Test` class:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = 1
        self.value2 = 2

    def setvalue1(self, value):
        self.value1 = value
```

Comment: In which way is adding useless properties a "fix" ? The only broken things in the OP's class were indentation and the lack of the `__init__` method (or more exactly what should have been in the `__init__` method directly at the class level).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You are quite right; I've removed the useless properties :)