# dynamically mapping function name using getattr in python

Tags: python

```
import json

class Myclass():

    def __init__(self):

        with open("file_name.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

        for key in data:
            print key
            key = getattr(self,'func_name')

    def func_name(self,arg):
        print "Pass"

obj = Myclass()
obj.func_name("test")
obj.key_from_file("test")
```

Output:

```
key_from_file
Pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_at.py", line 22, in <module>
    obj.key_from_file("test")
AttributeError: Myclass instance has no attribute 'key_from_file'
```

I want to dynamically map all key in json file to func_name, so whenever we call obj.key_from_file("test") which should call obj.func_name("test")

How to do that ?

Comment: I don't get the question. At all. Why would you expect `obj` to have a `key_from_file` method even though you never defined one? And what's the point of the `func_name` method?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you programmatically set an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setAttr` for setting the attribute in the object:

```
import json

class Myclass():

    def __init__(self):
        with open("file_name.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)
        for key in data:
            print key
            setattr(self, key, self.func_name) #we create an attr with the key as name and the funct_name function as value.

    def func_name(self,arg):
        print "Pass"

obj = Myclass()
obj.func_name("test")
obj.key_from_file("test")
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/LightpinkOutgoingCarat)

Comment: How does this answer the question? The code will still throw the same exception.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, no it will not, if the key is on the json file

Comment: So the question is literally just "How do I dynamically set an attribute"? We have dupes for that.