# Create self attributes in python using for loop when using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Within pytorch, creating layers, can be semi automated, thus the reason for using a for loop.

One of the main issues is that these layers cannot stored within a list or dictionary or else back propagation will not work.

Thus the reason for a work around.

Within the object, assigning new `self` attributes

How do i replace this

```
self.res1 = 1
self.res2 = 2
self.res3 = 3
```

with this

```
for i in range(2):
  res_name = 'res'+str(i+1)
  self.res_name = i
```

Now that i have created objects this way, how can I access them in the same way. For example, if we assume self.res_name is now an object?

```
for i in range(2):
   res_name = 'res'+str(i+1)
   out = self.res_name(out)
```

Comment: This isn't really maintainable. Maybe you need a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Maybe you can overwrite `__getattr__` & `__setattr__` to get the same effect without going into dynamic attributes.

Comment: Use a dict() ...

Comment: Probably `self.res` wants to be a list

Comment: A dictionary cannot be used in pytorch, as it returns an empty parameter list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use a `dict` or `list` instead. But if you really want this for some reason, you can try `setattr(x, attr, 'magic')`.

Thus, in your case, it's

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    res_name = 'res' + str(i)
    setattr(self, res_name, i)
```

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute) for more info.