# How to concatenate a parameter name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my current code:

```
def flag_a_device_status(context, var):
    if var == '40D':
         context.holder.default_40D = True
    elif var= '212F':
         context.holder.default_212F = True
    elif 
    elif 
    else:...
```

As you can see, `var` is a parameter passing from the upstream code, and its value could be "40D", "200F", "212F", etc.  And based on its string value, I need to turn on different flag under `context.holder`, such as `default_40D`, `default_212F`, etc.

Is there a better way to handle that in Python? Something as if:

```
context.holder.default_"var" = True
```

Comment: Why don't you keep the `default_` things in a dictionary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you programmatically set an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `exec` for your scenario. One more thing, you don't need to have those many if-else statements, for that you can handle it with the below way.

i.e., in your code you're going to add `exec(f'context.header.default_{var} = True')`

```
class Context:
  def __init__(self, default_40D = False, default_212F = False):
    self.default_40D = default_40D
    self.default_212F = default_212F

  def test(self):
    print(self.default_40D)
    print(self.default_212F)

variables = ['40D', '212F']
def flag_a_device_status(context, var):
    if var in variables:
         exec(f'context.default_{var} = True')

context = Context()

flag_a_device_status(context, '40D')

context.test()
```

Comment: Please don't recommend that anyone use `exec`.

Comment: True! totally agreed with that, it is bad stuff though, it's one of the answers to this question.  Will add that to the answer as well.