# Python: How to generate the code on the fly?

Tags: python

I've got a problem, I have to generate program on the fly and then execute it.
How could we do this?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Specifically, what do you want your code to do? Higher order functions might be in order. Each one could serve as a sort of template for the functionality that you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the eval() function to execute code from a string

An example would be:

```
import math

test=r"dir(math)"

eval(test)
```

Output

```
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'hypot', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

However using eval is very unsafe, I suggest you go through [using eval() safely](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to evaluate expression or some python code use `eval` or `literal_eval` depends on your requirements...

If you need to generate .py  files, you may need code generator, here is the basic code generator: http://effbot.org/zone/python-code-generator.htm
and then you can execute your code using `execfile`

Answer (score 3):

smart way: metapython -- http://metapython.org/

much-derided and not-generally-respected way: `eval()` -- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

why do you want to do this, may I ask?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the interpreter, just type 'python' from the command line.