# Assigning an (OOP) object to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I was trying to assign a Python object to another *in-place* using a member function such as `replace_object()` below. However, as you can see, `object_A` remains unchanged and the only way to copy `object_B` is to create an entirely new object `object_C`, which defeats the purpose of in-place assignment.

What is going on here and how can I make the assignment in-place?

```
class some_class():

    def __init__(self, attribute):

        self.attribute = attribute

    def replace_object(self, new_object):

        self = new_object

        # Does this line even have any effect?
        self.attribute = new_object.attribute 

        self.new_attribute = 'triangle'

        return self

object_A = some_class('yellow')
print(object_A.attribute)       # yellow
object_B = some_class('green')
object_C = object_A.replace_object(object_B)
print(object_A.attribute)       # yellow
print(object_C.attribute)       # green

#print(object_A.new_attribute)  # AttributeError!
print(object_B.new_attribute)   # triangle
print(object_C.new_attribute)   # triangle
```

I also tried to play around with deep copies using `copy.copy()`, but to no avail.

An interesting twist to this is that if I replace

```
object_C = object_A.replace_object(object_B)
```

with

```
object_A = object_A.replace_object(object_B)
```

then I get what I want. But why can't the same result be achieved by the statement `self = new_object` statement within `replace_object()`?

PS: I have a very good reason to do this in-place assignment, so although it may not be best practice in general, just go along with me here.

Comment: That's not how assignment works in Python, and trying to change those kinds of language mechanics is unlikely to go well even for experts. [Here's a quick guide to what assignment actually does in Python.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Could you explain *why* you think you need to do this?

Comment: @ScottHunter ... because the apparent alternative, namely `object_A = object_A.replace_object(object_B)`, seems redundant.

Comment: Why can't you just copy all the attributes to mirrow the ones in the object passed in, or however you are defining "equality".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The point is precisely that I _cannot_ copy all the attributes within `replace_object()`.

Comment: @Tfovid of course you can. Just dispense with trying to do `self = other_object`, then go through the attributes you care about, e.g. `attr1, attr2` etc, and do `self.attr1 = other_object.attr1; self.attr2 = other_object.attr2; ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please look at the code I posted: The statement `self.attribute = new_object.attribute` does exactly what you're suggesting, but it does not work. So no, you cannot just copy the attributes.

Comment: As I already explained, that is because you do `self = new_object`. Don't do that, because now when you do: `self.attribute = new_object.attribute` the statement is equivalent to `new_object.attribute = new_object.attribute`, i.e. completely pointless.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sorry, yes, I get it now. Although I still kind of find it inelegant to have to iterate through all the attributes :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'assign an object to another'. You can assign new and existing objects to new and existing names.

`self = new_object` only says 'from now on the name `self` will refer to `new_object`', and does nothing to the old object. (Note `self` is just a variable name like any other and only by convention refers to an object within a class definition.)

The subsequent command `self.attribute = new_object.attribute` has no effect because `self` has already become a duplicate label for the `new_object`.

You could copy all the properties of a new object to the old object. You would end up with two distinct objects with different names and identical properties. A test of equality (`a == b`) would return false unless you [overrode the equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) for these objects.

To copy all the properties inline you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243836/how-to-copy-all-properties-of-an-object-to-another-object-in-python):

```
def replace_object(self, new_object):
    self.__dict__ = new_object.__dict__.copy() # just a shallow copy of the attributes
```

There are very likely better ways to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: So what's the alternative? Isn't `object_A = object_A.replace_object(object_B)` both redundant and inelegant?

Comment: I've edited the answer with a suggestion of how you can copy the properties. But find it difficult to see a scenario where this is a useful approach.

Comment: That could do it, thanks. But why does it have to be a shallow copy? Why not just `self.__dict__ = new_object.__dict__`?

Comment: If you do that then the old object's attribute dictionary will always point to the new object's attribute dictionary (both names point to the same object). E.g. if you type `new_object.x = 30` then you will find that `old_object` also now has an attribute `x` equal to 30. Maybe that's what you want though?

Comment: Actually, I just opted for looping through all the attributes and  using `__setattr__()` instead. Is this kocher or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: It's more or less the same. `.copy()` will copy all of the new object's attributes indiscriminately. With your approach you can control which attributes are copied. This will take more lines of code but might be preferable as you can avoid copying unwanted or irrelevant attributes.