# Python - Wrapping object with a class and preserving its methods

Tags: python-3.x

I have a scenario where I can accept different objects (classes or functions) and I wrap them with a class to enhance their capabilities and I want to still be able to access their native methods (that I didn't write).

With the `__call__` function, I can easily pass the arguments to the native `__call__` function, but how can I still route the functions I don't know beforehand to their native functions?

For example:

```
import modules.i.didnt.write as some_classes
import modules.i.didnt.write2 as some_functions

class Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, module, attr_name):

        self.obj = getattr(module, attr_name)
        self.extra_args = ....


    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.obj(*args, **kwargs)

    def added_functionality(self, ...):
        ....


wrapped_class = Wrapper(some_classes, 'class_a')
wrapped_function = Wrapper(some_functions, 'func_a')

wrapped_class(a=1, b=2)
wrapped_function(a=10, b=20)

wrapped_class.native_method(c=10)   # <--------------
```

In this example, the last one will fail, because `native_method` does not exist in the `Wrapper` class, but it exists in the `class_a` original structure.

How can I support the native functionality while adding my own?
Am I taking the wrong approach? Is there a better way to do it? Is it even possible?

Comment: This should also be tagged with [tag:python]...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy all properties of an object to another object, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243836/how-to-copy-all-properties-of-an-object-to-another-object-in-python)

Comment: so in this code it just so happens that `class_a` has a `__call__` function?

Comment: does it have to be literally the same `Wrapper` class? usually do modify behavior you inherit from a class, you can just create two wrappers one for functions and one for a class

Comment: Yep, it just so happens that it has a `__call__` function. I get what you are saying. I'm open for a split solution - but I can't tell from which class the classes will inherit